# Can an inline variable be changed after initialization in C++17?

Tags: c++, dll, c++17, compiler-specific, inline-variable

My scenario is the following (it worked in clang but not in gcc)

liba.hpp:

```
inline int MY_GLOBAL = 0;
```

libother.cpp: (dll)

```
#include "myliba.hpp"

void myFunc() {
    //
    MYGLOBAL = 28;
}
```

someexe.cpp:

```
RunAppThatUsesBothLibAandLibOther();
```

The problem is that the inline variable was showing 0 in places where I expected 28 because it was alrady modified at run-time. MSVC disagrees with this, but clang does the thing I would expect.

The question is: *can inline variables be modified at run-time in my scenario?* (I solved the problem by de-inlining the variable.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `inline` variables can be modified after initialization.

However, DLLs are strange things on Windows with MSVC. To a close approximation, each DLL is modelled as its own C++ program, with an entirely independent runtime. Therefore, there is one copy of your `inline` variable for the main program, and another for the DLL.

Comment: Similar *caveat emptor*: Linking the same static lib into two DLLs (which you then link with the same program) will produce two copies of all the static lib variables.

Comment: This would mean, I guess, that I must use non-inline variables. Is this correct? At least in the case of multiple dlls where I want to share a value changed at runtime...

Comment: Yes, you would need to use non-`inline` variables. You would also need to ensure they were exported from one DLL and imported from there in all other places.