# What can go wrong when using inline variable inside a dll?

Tags: c++, dll, c++17

I wonder what happens when using inline variables and making my code into a dll. Will I get one inline variable binary implementation in the dll, and another inline variable binary implementation in the executable file which is built by the code using the dll and including the header containing the inline variable?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: There are no inline variables...

Comment: @ALX23z wrong since C++17 source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline  Now working out this works between EXEs and DLLs (as the standard does not know these exist) is taxing my brain.

Comment: Possibly relevant: ["Can an inline variable be changed after initialization in C++17??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195606/can-an-inline-variable-be-changed-after-initialization-in-c17/59195808#59195808).

Comment: so it is seemed that it is impossible to use the inline variable in the dll correctly. And I can not use inline static variable in the template class by this reason.Is there some method to solve this problem?